# Android - Firebase disk persistence does not seem to work after reboot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My use case is as follows:
On a mobile device that may or may not have an internet connection, register some user data.
After a certain date, all data needs to be synced to a Firebase database.

Because the device isn't guaranteed to have an internet connection over the span of several days, it's possible that the device may be rebooted.

I've enabled disk persistence in the code of the Application class:

```
@Override public void onCreate() { 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); 
    super.onCreate();
}
```

This works as intended for queued write operations when I disable network connectivity and re-enable network connectivity, including when I exit and restart the application and then re-enable network connectivity.

```
DatabaseReference devicesRef = database.getReference().child(DEVICES);
devicesRef.child(deviceID).setValue("test");
```

However, when I exit the application and reboot the device, the write operations don't seem to trigger.

Am I doing something wrong or is this use case simply not supported by Firebase? Should I just write the data on application start?

I've reviewed this question which seems identical, but it doesn't provide any answers:

[Does firebase realtime database persistence sync data after device reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962028/does-firebase-realtime-database-persistence-sync-data-after-device-reboot/49962382#49962382)

Additional info:

- Motorola Moto E20
- Target SDK: 33
- Firebase Android BoM: 32.0.0

Comment: Update: I _may_ have identified the problem and the solution. The disk persistence works, but the queued writes are only triggered when another Firebase DB operation is done. So by simply making another read or write, the queued writes are executed and cleared from the queue. There is probably a more elegant solution for this.